# Image manipulation - converting transparent pixels before saving as jpg

Tags: c#, image-manipulation

I'm saving a an image with a transparent background to jpeg.
Is there a way to convert the transparent pixels to a certain color without iterating on all the pixels?

This is the code I'm using (also - is the first line a common way to do it? are there different encoders?)

```
public void SaveImage(Bitmap image, string path)
{
    var encoder = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders().FirstOrDefault(c => c.MimeType == "image/jpeg");
    var encodeParams = new EncoderParameters(1);
    encodeParams.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, (long)100);

    image.Save(path, encoder, encodeParams);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual solution is to make a bitmap image with your desired background color, render your image to it, and save/convert this bitmap as an image.

Check [Graphics.FromImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.fromimage.aspx). This will give you a Graphics rendering object for a bitmap.

Answer (score 1):

```
image.MakeTransparent(image.GetPixel(0, 0));
```

But this can saved as png because sadly jpg doesn't support transparency

Comment: I already have transparent pixels, I want to turn all of them to non-transparent